# Query a object's array based on array element in Mongo DB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want a query to fetch document from an array of string which are embedded in object.

### Documents

```
{
"_id" : "3YKncXW8jGYqBG2zx",
"roles" : {
    "public" : [ 
        "dashboard"
    ],
    "private" : [ 
        "Sanity", 
        "run_api", 
        "Dashboard"
    ]
  }
}

{
"_id" : "nwS84s8bHNdS7N2vh",
"roles" : {
    "private" : [ 
        "Sanity", 
        "run_api", 
        "Dashboard"
    ]
  }
}
```

### query I used

`db.getCollection('rolesCollection').find({roles : {"private" : [ "Sanity", "run_api" , "Dashboard" }})`

### result

0 documents.

### result

3YKncXW8jGYqBG2zx

nwS84s8bHNdS7N2vh

Can someone help me getting _id of documents which have `private` array with elements `"Sanity", "run_api" and "Dashboard"`

Comment: You can use `db.getCollection('rolesCollection').find({"roles.private": {$all: [ 
        "Sanity", 
        "run_api", 
        "Dashboard"
    ], $size: 3}});` if you don`t care about order of elements.

Comment: @Veeram Thank you that helps :)